# Creating .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have written the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /afs/asu.edu/users/a/r/s/arsingh3/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Only valid users can access "
<Files "CSE001.html">
  Allow Alice John Bob Dave
</Files>
```

I'm trying to give access to some users to a particular webpage.
Is it possible to do that or do I have to create separate .htaccess file for each user??
I don't know for some reason it is not working properly.
Please have a look and suggest any errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for .htgroup

Create a group file.
Call it /afs/asu.edu/users/a/r/s/arsingh3/www/.htgroup and have it look something like this:

cse1: Alice John Bob Dave

... where Alice, John, Bob, Dave are the usernames.
Then modify the .htaccess file in the directory to look like this:

```
AuthUserFile /afs/asu.edu/users/a/r/s/arsingh3/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /afs/asu.edu/users/a/r/s/arsingh3/www/.htgroup 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Only valid users can access " 
<Files "CSE001.htm">  
    require group cse1 
</Files>
```

Note that AuthGroupFile now points to your group file and that group cse1 (rather than individual user Alice) is now required for access.

http://www.euronet.nl/~arnow/htpasswd/documentation.html

Use this website to generate your passwords in .htpasswd
http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Note:  You can also do multiple groups.
http://www.washington.edu/webinfo/htaccess/weblogin.html

```
<Files "CSE001.htm">
    require group A
    require group cse1
    require user Dave
</Files>
```